# Form data always going null for text field in angular js and rest service spring

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS and not sure where I am missing, though I know its a minor mistake which I am committing. Please help me out with below scenario.

I have a form where in I write a post {textArea} and click submit button, which calls ng-click=createPost() method.

It goes to controller.js which is:

app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'PostFactory', '$location', function ($scope, PostFactory, $location) {

```
            /* callback for ng-click 'createUser': */
            $scope.createPost = function() {
                alert("in createPost" + $scope.post.postText);
                alert("in createPost" + $scope.post);
                PostFactory.create($scope.post)
                $scope.posts.push($scope.post.postText);
                $scope.post = "";
                $location.path('/view1');
            }

            $scope.posts = PostFactory.query();

            /*UserFactory.get({}, function (userFactory) {
                $scope.firstname = userFactory.firstName;
            })*/
        }]);
```

and my service.js is:

```
     var services = angular.module('ngdemo.services', ['ngResource']);
            //alert("In services");
            services.factory('PostFactory', function ($resource) {
               // alert("Reached services.js");
                return $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts', {}, {

                    query: {
                        method: 'GET',
                        //params: {},
                        isArray: true
                    },
                    create: {method: 'POST'}
                })
            });
```

my Spring controller which is exposed as service and have post method:

```
    @RequestMapping(/*value = "/add",*/ method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String addPost(@ModelAttribute(value = "") Post post,       BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println("Post value : " + post.getPostText());
    //post.setPostId();
    post.setPostTags("#dummy");
    postService.addPost(post);
    return "redirect:/";
    }
```

my form :

```
  <form novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal">

    <!-- Textarea -->
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <textarea ng-model="post.postText" rows="4" cols="300" name="inputQuestion" id="post.postText" class="form-control expand" placeholder="What you want to pingle today?"></textarea>
        </div>

    <br>
    <!-- Button -->


        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button ng-click='createPost()' class="btn btn-default plus">  Pingle it!      </button>
        </div>
    </div>

  </form>
```

Problem is : always Post value in controller is coming as null, have tried with $scope.post and $scope.postText but no joy!

Please let me know where I am missing?????

UPDATE:

How can we pass a form object to Spring Controller in controller.js?? Post is my Domain object

Answer (score 1):

it worked, once I replaced @ModelAttribute with @RequestBody, somehow it was preventing the data to be populated in my object. After setting @RequestBody, it worked!Thanks all!